# How to unregister MediaButtonReceiver onDestroy?

Tags: android, service, audio-streaming, android-pendingintent

iam using MediaButtonReciever in my Streaming service to listen handle head sets and different devices action 
i'm declaring it in Manifest like this

```
   <receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The actions works just fine as long as the app in the background
once the app is terminated if i clicked on any MediaButton it crashes as the media button with the following crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find any Service that handles android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON or a media browser service implementation
```

the problem is the receiver keeps receiving even if the app is destroyed, now how can i unregister the receiver once the app close ?
i have tried audioManager.unregister(MediaButtonReciever) but its depreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that i was using the default class in my manifest like this

```
 <receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

which was wrong the the receiver automatically unregister after onReceive() is finished

> Once you return from onReceive(), the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active, **[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle)**

so all idid was i extened MediaRecieverButton in my custom class `MyMediaButtonReceiver`
and edited my manifest like this

```
<receiver android:name=".MyMediaButtonReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

and it worked just fine

Comment: Just extending MediaReceiverButton doesn't work. You have to do that plus override onReceive method in your extended class, calling super.onReceive() inside a try-catch that captures IllegalStateException.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005517/6196455

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to handle buttons when your app is running, then you shouldn't declare this in the manifest. You should register and unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically in your code when you want it to respond to events.

To register the receiver, do:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MediaButtonReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

When you are done (ie: in `onDestroy()` of your component), unregister the receiver like this:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got this error and I solve it by set enable flag of My service to true:

android:enabled="true"

```
  <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:multiprocess="true">
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```